# Combining results from two queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like the one as below:

```
 id     friends_id  
 4      2
 4      3
 5      3
```

I need the friends_id from this table common to the id values 4 and 5.  So the query must return only the value 3 common to bot 4 and 5 .

```
friends_id
    3
```

How can I achieve this in "MYSQL".

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  friends_id
FROM    TableName
WHERE   id IN (4, 5)
GROUP   BY friends_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abbed9/3)

Assuming, however, `id` is unique, you can omit `DISTINCT`

```
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```